# Is there currently a measurable shortage of pilots?

Tags: airline-operations, career

Is there a clearly identifiable and measurable pilot shortage right now? If so, is it a shortage of pilots or of captains, i.e. more experienced pilots? Are airlines changing any personnel rules - like time to go from first officer to captain - that would imply there is a pilot shortage?

If any shortage is for captains couldn't airlines 'upgrade' first officers to fill the places? But presumably that would create a shortage of FOs in turn.

Comment: Who says there's a pilot shortage?

Comment: Ok, for those that don't want to answer...just don't waste your time. Cheers.

Comment: Yes there is a pilot shortage but mostly experienced pilots, go have a look at all the recruitment sites...captains are urgently wanted from the middle east to asia..

Comment: If there is a shortage then the cost of pilots will increase. If pilot salaries, paid benefits, paid training, paid holidays etc. are increasing, then pilots are in increasing demand. That's probably the clearest way to identify a shortage. In theory airlines in one country could handle a shortage without increasing wages by importing pilots from other, cheaper countries - i.e. increasing the supply - but that should also be identifiable somehow, e.g. more working visas issued to pilots.

Comment: mizzu, it isn't that people don't want to answer, but rather that your question is too broad to have an actual definitive answer.  As the first comment on  your question asks, Which country are you even talking about?  As he also says, our site is not designed or intended for open ended discussions, but rather for questions which can have a rather specific narrow definitive answer (Aviation SE is **not** a forum, but rather a Q&A site).  Please read [ask] and look around our [help] for more info. This site is a **great** resource, but is for a different purpose than what you may be used to!

Comment: "*Yes there is a pilot shortage*": If you're not under a NDA, maybe you could share your source to make the question less open.

Comment: @Federico although badly phrased (ie as opinion/discussion), this is a question with a quantifiable, reference-able answer. Perhaps worth cleaning up the question to make it less inviting of opinion, but I do think it's valid

Comment: @JonStory my comment was on the original version. the current version is already a much better one.

Comment: Ah my apologies - the mobile app doesn't make edits as clear so I hadn't spotted it had already changed

Answer (score 1):

Here in the US (because this varies around the world) [some sources](http://time.com/4257940/pilot-shortage/) do say [there is a pilot shortage](http://aviationweek.com/commercial-aviation/coming-us-pilot-shortage-real). There are many reasons that have been cited for the decrease in pilots here in the states. But the main points seem to be,

- Rising Costs of training
- FAA upping the required hours (250 -1500) for a full ATP ticket
- [Lower conversion from military pilots](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/columnist/cox/2013/03/18/ask-the-captain-are-most-airline-pilots-from-the-military/1994161/) (there was a time when many of the commercial pilots out there were former service pilots)
- [Lower Salary Prospects](http://thetruthabouttheprofession.weebly.com/professional-pilot-salaries.html): its no mystery that pilots don't make what they once did nor get the perks they once did.

Another factor that effects this once you are in the industry is the fact that "seniority" does not transfer over from airline to airline. Generally this is not an issue if you work for someone like American or Delta who have plenty of jobs and steady routes. But if you are captain at NotSoWellEstablishedAir and they go belly up you will most likely join one of the others lower in the ranks if not at the bottom.

Another thing that is worth mentioning is that it may be [more advantageous for a pilot to remain a very senior first officer instead of becoming a very junior captain](http://www.askthepilot.com/questionanswers/seniority/). You may have more power over your route choice, time off, and general schedule as a senior first officer than as a newly minted captain. For some pilots, like those who may be trying to start a family this may be seen as an advantage.

As for the [shortage over seas (outside the US)](http://news.blogs.cnn.com/2012/06/04/u-s-pilots-find-high-demand-high-pay-overseas/) that stems from different issues. First and foremost many countries have seen great and more importantly fast economic prosperity which has allowed them to get into the aviation game. A game traditionally filled with high costs and heavy regulations. As such many newly wealthy nations have been able to enter the aviation world much faster than their regulations and training programs can keep up with. The [FAA is almost 60 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Administration) with aviation regulations [dating back to the 30's with the CAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Aeronautics_Board). There are even some american issued pilots licensed signed by the [Wrights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers) them selves from the very early days. Other countries simply don't have the history of growing with aviation like the US and similar countries have had. Thus they have all these new planes but no one to fly them and no well established programs and regulations to create the pilots. In turn they are forced to import trained, certified pilots from elsewhere.

Comment: Wasn't the reason for increasing the requirement a huge surplus of pilots leading to absurdly low wages for F/Os on regional airlines? (Note: they didn't change requirement for ATPL, they changed the requirement for F/O to need full ATPL)

Answer (score -6):

I'll put it this way: There wouldn't be a pilot shortage if the pay was right and regulators would stop putting in place roadblocks to professional airline pilot training like the asinine 1500 hour rule for first officers.

The saddest thing about this nation's corps of professional pilots is that it's a profession of people who absolutely love what they do and are exploited and treated as wage slaves by company brass who know this.

At this point, though, things are beginning to change in the USA.  The airlines are faced with a glut of senior captains over 65 now and forced to take mandatory retirement.  With typical starting salaries for regional FOs being about \$18-\$22k based upon a realistic calculation of pay, being on duty for 14-16 hours a day, and forced to live in crowded apartments with several other pilots, it's no wonder that people pursuing a career as a professional pilot have dwindled.  This in contrast with the rising demand for pilots has created a situation where the airlines have no choice but to act.  Salaries are being increased, and many airlines are adopting their own flight training programs where they cover the costs to train promising candidates in exchange for a mandatory employment contract for an agreed upon length of time (usually about 7 or so years).

Comment: Sure.  The mandatory requirement for 1500 flight hours was a direct result of the crash of Colgan Air 3407, in Buffalo.  The NTSB lists the official cause of the crash to be the Capt. Renslow's inappropriate response to the stick shaker leading to aerodynamic stall of the airplane.  It also lists crew fatigue as one of the major factors leading to the crash as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is your opinion, not what I have asked. I'll rephrase: is there any study that shows that the 1500 hours requirement is detrimental or does not provide any benefit? Because if we have to bring opinions, I could argue that inappropriate responses can be a product of inexperience.

Comment: Accidents are caused by event chains; if one link fails, there is no accident.  Here you had 1) A low time CAPTAIN with mediocre aptitude at airmanship 2) an ill first officer 3) both are exhausted and fatigued from a long duty shift, which the FO comments there were no other viable financial alternatives for her (See the CVR transcript).  4) Both crew were paid less than 30k annually, limiting their living and commuting options further.

Comment: Combine all of this together and you have a ripe situation for a flight crew not paying attention to airspeed on final, then making a rookie mistake with a heavy twin, causing the stall and crash.

Comment: Sorry on the delay; the response is limited to about 700 characters; I need more than that to fully answer the question.

Comment: Now the 1500 hour rule for FOs was never a requirement in the past and to the best of my knowledge was never a contributing factor to other air transport accidents.  It hurts the industry by delaying the amount of time for new pilots to get a FO seat, forcing them to do flight instruction then possibly cargo hauling or some other means to earn hours for 2-4 more years after earning their wings.  As I said, it's just a asinine impediment, with little or no benefit for the airlines.

Comment: You make a reasonable case, but it's still your opinion. We try to give answers that are factual and supported by sources and studies, rather than opinions. Also remember that the question is about *whether* there is a pilot shortage, not the causes of it.

Comment: You don't need a double-blind study with 50TB of analysis to know that the new rules to little to enhance safety.  The burden lies with the regulators to produce compelling evidence that high time minimums will improve flight saftey.  My observations lead me to the conclusion that arbitrary hour minimums have not translated to higher a quality of pilot.

Comment: My opinion is supported by the evidence in the NTSB report on that crash.

Comment: This is a Q&A website. Your post does NOTHING to answer the question.

Comment: Yes it does answer the question.  It says that a pilot shortage does exist and is directly correlated to the fugitive nature of the business, low pay, strenuous working conditions, long hours, and brueaucracy interfering with the process of hiring new pilots.